# Equation numbering: how can I get (1.1), (2.1), (3.2) in the article class?

Tags: numbering

I know how to make them do 1, 2, 3....just need to know 1.1, 1.2, 3.2, 3.3 etc

```
\begin{align}

\end{align}
```

This will produce 1, 2, 3 etc, I know this but need the other.

Comment: Use `subequations`. See (possible duplicates) [How to reference equations using letters and numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494/5764); [How to number a set of equations separately from another set?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36192/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE, your question could be made a little clearer. A minimal working example from `\documentclass` until `\end{document}` could enable more users to answer your question.

Comment: The title of you post is very bad. It is essentially useless for other users that may face a similar issue, when they search for existing questions/answers on this site. That would be nice if you could reformulate it in a more descriptive way, as, for instance: Equation numbering: how can I get (1.1), (2.1), (3.2) in the article class?

Answer (score 27):

The question can also be interpreted that the first number of the composite equation number should be the section number. The other two classes `report` and `book` are using composite equation numbers, whose first part is the chapter number. The `article` class does not have chapters and uses plain equation numbers.

Package `amsmath` (this is used because of `align`) provides an easy way to add the section number:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
  \section{Equation numbering}
  \begin{align}
    a = a\\
    b = b\\
    c = c
  \end{align}

  \section{Second section}
  \begin{gather}
    d = d
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: `\numberwithin` was not recognized for me, but `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` worked.

Comment: @marts `\numberwithin` requires package `amsmath`, where it is defined, as I have written in the answer.

Comment: I know, I am using that package. I haven't been able to figure out why `\numberwithin` doesn't work. I've added the comment for other users who might stumble upon this problem.

Comment: @marts Then, make a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in a new question to have something to be analyzed. The example in the answer still works for me without problems.

Answer (score 18):

The [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package offers you the `subequations` environment; to get the desired formatting, you can redefine `\theequation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
y & = d \\
y & = cx+d \\
y & = bx^{2}+cx+d \\
y & = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
y & = d \\
y & = cx+d \\
y & = bx^{2}+cx+d \\
y & = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]